# Cisco Unity Connection 7 and Exchange 2010 Unified Messaging

Tags: cisco, exchange-2010, exchange

We are looking to get our Cisco Unity Connection 7 to store messages using Exchange Server 2010 Unified Messaging. Is anyone aware of any whitepaper/document/tutorial or other that they'd recommend we look into? We can't seem to find much. From what I here from our Cisco partner is that the connection works, but will be better in the next release.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity Connection 8.5 will do unified messaging with exchange. Versions prior to that will not.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/connection/8x/gui_reference/guide/8xcucgrg085.html

-Go0se